# How to display a div on any page except: homepage, checkout, success page?

Tags: magento-1.7, php

Currently this works for not displaying on the homepage but still displays on **`/checkout/cart`** & **`/onepage/`** pages.

```
<?php if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()): ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div>Example Content</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any advice would be really appreciated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to check if you are on checkout or cart page.
`$this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'checkout'` with your homepage conditions.